# NVIDIA Optimus, hybrid-graphics systems, How to configure them to meet my expectations

Tags: linux, graphics-card

For the past week I've been trying to install nvidia drivers on my dual-graphics laptop.

Right now I am using Debian 9 stretch -rc 3. Before that I was using Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 (Dual boot). Previous setup did not meet my expectations, therefor I switched completely to the Debian 9 stretch -rc 3 under the `amd64` architecture.

On the manufacturer's website, I could not find the specs for my laptop model, so I provided a link to the [Amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TZIK0F8). This page provides the most detailed technical specifications I was able to found on the net. I hope I didn't break any rules... I posted this page only with a single goal: provide you with technical data.

---

### **Where does my question come from?**

I used to use Ubuntu (14.x, 16.x) on the regular basis. And in order to correctly install nvidia drivers I had to do the following:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target

# reboot laptop to enter text mode...

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

# This is a repository with proprietary GPU drivers. 

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-XYZ

# XYZ is driver version.

sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target

# reboot laptop to start x-server.

# In Ubuntu "Additional Driver Utility" chose nvidia driver.

# Reboot one more time.
```

**AND EVERYTHING WAS WORKING CORRECTLY !!!**

I know that for sure because I use my laptop for scientific purposes, so I always install the `CUDA toolkit` later.

**And that is, at least for me, a strong indicator that I do not have `NVIDIA Optimus` setup. But I can be wrong...**

---

### How I tried to install the drivers on Debian and what the problem was:

At first I had to allow the use of `contrib` and `non-free` software in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then i just run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver
```

If I would stop here and restart my computer, I would see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFxmf.jpg).
If I continue and run `nvidia-xconfig`, I would destroy the debian (there would be noting but a blinking cursor, after the reboot).

---

### **A little more information:**

Below are results of few "info-gathering" commands. All of them were launched on `Debian 9 stretch -rc3`.

```
# Result of 'lspci':
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)

# Result of 'nvidia-detect':
No NVIDIA GPU detected.
```

On Debian in `Settings > Details > Graphics` I see than I am using Intel integrated card (`Intel® Haswell Mobile`).

Right now I have no means of checking it (other than installing ubuntu in place of the debian), but I remember that in Ubuntu's `Software & Updates` utility (in `Additional Drivers`), I could see entries about unrecognized Intel device (CPU was recognized correctly). Now I believe, but I might be wrong, that it was about Intel gpu.

**I also remember that on Ubuntu my nvidia gpu was recognized as VGA, not 3D.**

---

### **Questions:**

1. Do you think I have `NVIDIA Optimus` setup? Even though on Ubuntu I was able to use graphic card in normal fashion?
2. If not, how can i force my Debian to recognize my nvidia graphics as `VGA controller` not an `3D controller`? (Ubuntu was able to do that).
3. Do you thing that I was able to use nvidia card on Ubuntu normally,
   **ONLY** due to a fact, that my Intel card was not recognized?
4. I want to treat my laptop as a `multi-graphics` system, not as
   a `hybrid-graphics` system. How can I do this?
5. Is there a possibility that during Debian installation, my hardware
   was detected incorrectly, and therefore interpreted as a `NVIDIA Optimums` setup?

Comment: "yes" you have optimus I think, judging by the output of lspci *and* my limited understanding. As far as "why" it worked in one configuration and not the other: are the ubuntu commands you listed retrieving proprietary drivers, and is the debian GET retrieving  generic?

Comment: @Yorik Yes, Ubuntu commands listed earlier, are retrieving proprietary drivers. In case of Debian, I am not sure... [Debian package search](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia-driver) tells that `nvidia-driver` package is pre-compiled for following architectures: `amd64`, `armhf`, `i386`. Nevertheless, they are appropriate for me - I am using `amd64` architecture with support for `i386`. ("support" mean that I am downloading recommended packages for this architecture alongside with `amd64`)

Comment: @DavidPostill I did **NOT** crosspost. The other question was about installing the drivers on debian system. And i got my answers. I did not get it at first, because my situation was different then i thought. But when i get it I wanted explanations, and that is how this question was asked. No matter what you are thinking, those are two different, unrelated and separated questions.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have also discovered some other "game-changers" and i am in process of experimenting, and writing detailed answer to this question.

Comment: @Yorik I believe I have cracked this mystery box.

Answer (score 0):

I think I cracked this mystery box, so let my answer my own question. 
Right now I am kind of busy, and i am unable to write everything at once... Therefore i will be updating this answer in the future...

---

> Do you think I have NVIDIA Optimus setup? Even though on Ubuntu I was able to use graphic card in normal fashion?

***Answer:*** Yes, I have `NVIDIA Optimus` setup.

How do I know that?

1. `lspci` and `nvidia-detect` output must be the same as in my question.
2. It can be checked in `bios` options. If there is an option named `switchable-graphics`, one can be sure that he has `NVIDIA Optimus` setup. But that's not obligatory. It is possible to have `hybrid-graphics` without having this option. Also name can vary.
3. [List of nvidia GPUs with this technology](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus/supported-gpus)

---

> If not, how can i force my Debian to recognize my nvidia graphics as
>   VGA controller not an 3D controller? (Ubuntu was able to do that).

***Answer:*** I have `hybrid-graphics` therefor this is not possible to force my nvidia card to be recognized as a `VGA controller`. At least not when intel card is working.

In general if I would like to have my nvidia card recognized as `VGA controller` I would have to disable my intel card at bios level (I believe there is a way to disable it at boot time, but this may have some unexpected repercussions - not sure thought).

But I have to point out that disabling intel card at bios level might **not** be possible. Because of the way the two cards are wired together (at hardware level), or because `bios` will not have this option.

If I somehow succeed at disabling intel card, I would have to either re-install my `OS` (safest way to recognize nvidia card and configure software) or re-install everything related to the `x-server`.

If it turns out that it is possible to disable the graphics card at the boot time, or at the system run time (highly unlikely), in theory I could be able to prepare `bash script` that could switch my laptop between two setups: `single-graphics` system (either nvidia card will be online **or** intel card), or `hybrid-graphics` system (when both cards are online).

---

> Do you thing that I was able to use nvidia card on Ubuntu normally,
>   ONLY due to a fact, that my Intel card was not recognized?

***Answer:*** Yes, that was exactly what happen.

---

> I want to treat my laptop as a multi-graphics system, not as a
>   hybrid-graphics system. How can I do this?

***Answer:*** `NVIDIA Optimus` means that my intel gpu and my nvidia gpu are wired together. They use single output channel (at hardware level). And if I would like to config them as two independent devices at software level, this would prove impossible.

---

> Is there a possibility that during Debian installation, my hardware
>   was detected incorrectly, and therefore interpreted as a NVIDIA
>   Optimums setup?

***Answer:*** No, my setup was detected correctly.